# What's the difference between пользование and использование?

Tags: существительные, глаголы

1. I looked **пользование and использование** up in the dictionary but they look the same to me. They translate the english word "use" or "usage". Could you please explain in which contexts you can use these words, giving some examples?
2. I am also confused by the verbs **пользовать, использовать and воспользовать**. I think the first is imperfective, while the second and third one perfective.But which one of the last two makes the "couple" with пользовать? Which one is its perfective form?
   If you could also give examples of their usage that would help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Russian at its finest mindblowingness.

Comment: Edit: I had to write the verbs with the ending -ся but I forgot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Пользование** comes from the verb **пользоваться** (imperfective; **-ся** is mandatory: *пользовать* is not used in contemporary Russian) and means continuous (daily) consumer usage.

> Пользование холодильником обходится дорого.
>
> Пользоваться холодильником удобно.

**Использование** is used much wider and comes from the verb **использовать** (with perfective or imperfective sense), which has a form **использоватьcя** for passive voice.

> Использование солнечной энергии экологически выгодно.
>
> Использовать солнечную энергию непросто.                (imperfective
>   sense)
>
> Остатки вчерашнего ужина нужно использовать на завтрак. (perfective
>   sense)
>
> Отходы могут использоваться как топливо.                (passive)

**Воспользоваться** (**-ся** is mandatory; no related noun) is a perfective verb with the meaning 'to take advantage of smth.' or simply 'to use once something at one's disposal'.

> Он воспользовался предложением поехать в командировку в Китай.

Answer (score 4):

`Пользовать` means *лечить* as an outdated form. "Меня пользовали от холеры"

If used in the meaning of `использовать`, it means that the speaker is clueless about their own language but trying to sound informal (In my book that's almost as bad as `ложить`)

`Пользоваться` and `использовать` is *to use*, imperfect form. "Я использую утюг, чтобы гладить бельё" (sounds a bit silly), "Я пользуюсь утюгом, чтобы гладить бельё" (a bit less), "Я глажу бельё утюгом" (better)

`Воспользоваться` is also *to use*, perfect form (likely implies *once*). "Чтобы погладить бельё, я воспользовался утюгом"

`Использоваться` means that something gets used (for something). "Утюг используется для глажки белья"

`Воспользовать` does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

1. as far as their synonymy is concerned, their application is a matter of style
   with `ис-пользование` being more formal

also like the respondent before me indicated `пользование` can not only mean usage (of an object) but also administering (a medicine to a person), treatment (of a person with a medicine)

because `пользование` is a verbal noun not only from `пользовать-ся`, but  from `пользовать` as well

2.`воспользоваться` is a one-off instance of `пользоваться`, the action is both perfective and one-off, can be translated as 'to make use of'

> Я пользуюсь эти утюгом уже неделю
>
> На прошлой неделе я воспользовался этим утюгом

1st usage continues through the entire week, while the 2nd happened only once during the week

also `воспользоваться` lacks its own present tense form, instead the present tense form of `использовать` is employed

with Google you can look up some contexts they appear in

Answer (score 1):

1. *Пользование* is about contionuous actions, for example, legal term *Right of use* = *Право пользования*. While *использование* is a single shot usage, sort of *application*. Naturally, participle *used* correponds to *использованный*.
2. *Пользовать* is an outdated synonym for *to cure someone*, *воспользовать* is not a word at all. You probably mean reflexive forms - *пользоваться* and *воспользоваться*.

*Пользоваться* is imperfective. *Воспользоваться* is perfective. But note that they both correspond to "*to use*", and not to "*to be used*". It's rather sort of "I use smth. for myself".

*Использовать(ся)* is both perfective and imperfective. It means *make use of* (or *to be used* - reflexive form).